# How to optimize tree like fetching from WP rest-api (with CPT & ACF)

Tags: php, json, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch tree-like data from WordPress rest API and save it as an array. I have a custom post type and every "post" in that CPT has custom fields "mom" and "dad". Those fields are relational ACF fields that link to another post (that belong to the same CPT).
So the child post "only knows" its parents and then if we want to fetch the grandparent, we have to go and check the parents of the parents.

Structure:

```
person
-dad
--dad´s dad
--dad´s mom
-mom
--mom´s dad
--mom´s mom
```

I would like to create a simple array of the family tree, but it's taking ages to fetch it and I think it could be optimized but not sure how.

The current structure for creating the family tree array:

```
function fetchFamilyTree($horse_id) {
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://..../wp-json/wp/v2/horse/' . $horse_id );

    // Exit if error.
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the body.
    $horse_info = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    // Exit if nothing is returned.
    if ( empty( $horse_info ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !empty( $horse_info ) ) {
        $tree = array();
        $suku['i'] = $horse_info->acf->dad;
        $suku['ii'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['i']);
        $suku['iii'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['ii']);
        $suku['iie'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['ii']);
        $suku['ie'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['i']);
        $suku['iei'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['ie']);
        $suku['iee'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['ie']);
        $suku['e'] = $horse_info->acf->mom;
        $suku['ei'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['e']);
        $suku['eii'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['ei']);
        $suku['eie'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['ei']);
        $suku['ee'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['e']);
        $suku['eei'] = haeHevosenIsa($suku['ee']);
        $suku['eee'] = haeHevosenEma($suku['ee']);
        return $tree;
    }

}
```

"haeHevosenEma" and "haeHevosenIsa" are helper functions like this to fetch the dad's or mom's id:

```
function haeHevosenEma($horse_id) {
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://..../wp-json/wp/v2/horse/' . $horse_id );

    // Exit if error.
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the body.
    $horse_info = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

    // Exit if nothing is returned.
    if ( empty( $horse_info ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !empty( $horse_info ) ) {
        return $horse_info->acf->ema;
    }
}
```

And no, I cannot save the data as an array to the person's profile. Every single person should be "their own post" and this relational data structure is key for other use cases.

Edit// Here's an example of the page load (over 52s) - something is wrong clearly. Without this family tree fetching the load time is under 2s.

[image of the page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZNLQ.png)

Comment: Do you have control over the WordPress side? If so, I would do the bulk of the code there with native/local queries, and then create a new dedicated endpoint /get-family-tree that accepts an ID and performs all of the logic. If you perform this all over REST it will result in multiple REST calls that cannot share any caching information. Assuming you can do this in a custom endpoint, I think this would be a case where you'd just want to get all posts (of your type) into a giant array that you can continuously walk until you reach the appropriate depth.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisHaas! I was able to work around the performance issue by creating a custom endpoint. Didn't even think that haha. Such a simple fix.